# In localhost and through a proxy: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: email, symfony, swiftmailer

I have an application with symfony2 and I´m using swiftmailer in order to send email. The point is that i´m accessing through a proxy and I don´t know if the error is due to this. 
This is my configuration file(config.yml)

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  gmail
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:       smtp.gmail.com
    username:   myusername@gmail.com
    password:   mygmailpass
    delivery_address: mydeliveryaddress@miserver.com

$host = 'dev' == $this->container->getParameter('kernel.environment') ? 'http://localhost' : 'http://www.site.com/web/app.php';
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Invitacion a Misitio.com')
                    ->setFrom('myusername@gmail.com')
                    ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
                    ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView('MyBundle:User:inviteFriendEmail.html.twig',array(
                            'token' => $token,
                            'user'  => $user,
                            'host'  => $host  
                           ))
                    );
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

I have tested other solutions in this forum and still the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the correct port, as gmail may use non-standard port.

Comment: I have tested with 587 and nothing. Any ideas of a port number that I can use?

Comment: Try port 465 as suggested here: http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: Also, try making sure you have the php_openssl module enabled on the server.

Comment: I have tested also and the same error.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment was a mistake. I don´t see the php_openssl in my php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Since this is connecting in a way Google deems not secure, you need to enable it before Google will permit access. There is a setting in your account that you need to enable.

Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and make sure 'Enable' is selected.

If that option is not available, you are presumably using a Google apps account (their business one), in which case access is controlled by that account's administrator.

If it still doesn't connect, try using the actual IP address of smtp.gmail.com in place of it. Since I found that domain resolves to an IPv6 address - not an IPv4 one - and PHP did not want to connect to that.

It's not ideal using an IP in place of a domain since it could change, but if it works at least you know where to concentrate on